# Difficulty in construction of an age pyramid

Tags: probability-or-statistics

INSEE the french economic statistic provider gives the data to construct an age pyramid as follow --- the data has been extracted with mathematica

for males

```
m=  {375301., 386444., 388571., 395224., 399798., 411273., 409974., 
    411160., 409128., 416521., 407867., 405266., 402933., 406016., 
    412048., 421114., 404408., 399542., 389842., 387386., 377748., 
    361790., 355598., 372001., 373723., 378834., 376348., 379519., 
    380054., 384618., 384804., 381879., 379210., 404101., 407789., 
    414886., 392867., 387833., 392934., 383131., 393548., 418549., 
    440843., 452887., 448856., 439785., 430238., 424829., 422819., 
    433382., 434562., 437581., 432484., 416168., 415676., 413461., 
    409280., 399063., 395888., 389819., 383308., 383795., 372386., 
    377394., 366631., 381169., 370698., 370458., 359965., 338567., 
    252587., 243895., 234663., 215924., 188793., 193056., 197482., 
    189589., 179984., 174402., 163136., 157720., 142724., 139104., 
    125494., 114298., 96198., 84893., 71483., 60336., 49822., 39524., 
    31336., 24670., 18835., 13864., 5876., 3507., 1946., 1260., 1130., 
    968., 488., 350., 231., 179.}
```

for females

```
 f= {358397., 369044., 370305., 374957., 382669., 391063., 389825., 
   392278., 390713., 396610., 388589., 386924., 384382., 386032., 
   393155., 401263., 382722., 381673., 370414., 370901., 364179., 
   350937., 348432., 365904., 372969., 380064., 383041., 388514., 
   388991., 398308., 396483., 398032., 391630., 417629., 423251., 
   426437., 403575., 395808., 397809., 388493., 399157., 420531., 
   444918., 455485., 452475., 443853., 438708., 436616., 433360., 
   443394., 445043., 452670., 447656., 431500., 433817., 431185., 
   431045., 421231., 421791., 419369., 415861., 415005., 406147., 
   413990., 403282., 418967., 412927., 409442., 400765., 381494., 
   287013., 281008., 272477., 251224., 226014., 236255., 247953., 
   243974., 239400., 238560., 233509., 233675., 220211., 221785., 
   207813., 199911., 177746., 162828., 147133., 132731., 118113., 
   99694., 84923., 71615., 57824., 45756., 20755., 13293., 9197., 6124., 
   4666., 5124., 3040., 1790., 1239., 1464.}
```

and of course for the labels

```
 `l = {0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 
 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 
 29., 30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38., 39., 40., 41., 42., 
 43., 44., 45., 46., 47., 48., 49., 50., 51., 52., 53., 54., 55., 56., 
 57., 58., 59., 60., 61., 62., 63., 64., 65., 66., 67., 68., 69., 70., 
 71., 72., 73., 74., 75., 76., 77., 78., 79., 80., 81., 82., 83., 84., 
 85., 86., 87., 88., 89., 90., 91., 92., 93., 94., 95., 96., 97., 98., 
 99., 100., 101., 102., 103., 104., 105 ou plus}` 

PairedBarChart[h1, f1]
```

gives

[image]

There are many problems

1) the result is unreadable due to the overcrowding of bins.

2) I was unable to transform the label in the good format which must be of the type {"a", "b", "c"} --- so how to add "" to a list of data ( I know I must transform initialy an expression in string but nothing I tried haw worked.

3) how to agregate data say 5 by 5 the the last entry managed differently
to obtain a age pyramid of the type 1-5, 6-10... more than

( Incidently I think that one of the big problems of the documentation of Mathematica in what concerns statistics is to postulate taht data come within Mathematica itself )

Ps I am always late to help other because I have no warning for new questions. Is there a way to have an alert when a question arrive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
PairedBarChart[
 Append[Total /@ Partition[Most[f], 5], Last[f]],
 Append[Total /@ Partition[Most[m], 5], Last[m]],
 ChartLabels -> Append[StringTemplate["``-``"][5 (# - 1), 5 (# - 1) + 4] & /@ Range[21], "105 ou plus"],
 BarSpacing -> {1.5 10^6, Automatic, Automatic}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To convert your list of labels to strings you could have used `ToString /@ l`.

Comment: very nice partitioning and labeling using `StringTemplate` (something to add to my 'useful  things'pile).   :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a hack but perhaps it can be modified as required:

```
df[lst_, val_] := 
 Catenate@MapThread[Table[#2, Round[#1/1000]] &, {lst, val}]
male = df[m, lab];
female = df[f, lab];
PairedHistogram[male, female, Automatic, "Count", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x 1000 count", "Age(years)"}, 
 ChartStyle -> {{LightRed, LightBlue}}, 
 ChartLegends -> {"Female", "Male"}]
```

[image]

Data:

```
m = {375301., 386444., 388571., 395224., 399798., 411273., 409974., 
   411160., 409128., 416521., 407867., 405266., 402933., 406016., 
   412048., 421114., 404408., 399542., 389842., 387386., 377748., 
   361790., 355598., 372001., 373723., 378834., 376348., 379519., 
   380054., 384618., 384804., 381879., 379210., 404101., 407789., 
   414886., 392867., 387833., 392934., 383131., 393548., 418549., 
   440843., 452887., 448856., 439785., 430238., 424829., 422819., 
   433382., 434562., 437581., 432484., 416168., 415676., 413461., 
   409280., 399063., 395888., 389819., 383308., 383795., 372386., 
   377394., 366631., 381169., 370698., 370458., 359965., 338567., 
   252587., 243895., 234663., 215924., 188793., 193056., 197482., 
   189589., 179984., 174402., 163136., 157720., 142724., 139104., 
   125494., 114298., 96198., 84893., 71483., 60336., 49822., 39524., 
   31336., 24670., 18835., 13864., 5876., 3507., 1946., 1260., 1130., 
   968., 488., 350., 231., 179.};
f = {358397., 369044., 370305., 374957., 382669., 391063., 389825., 
   392278., 390713., 396610., 388589., 386924., 384382., 386032., 
   393155., 401263., 382722., 381673., 370414., 370901., 364179., 
   350937., 348432., 365904., 372969., 380064., 383041., 388514., 
   388991., 398308., 396483., 398032., 391630., 417629., 423251., 
   426437., 403575., 395808., 397809., 388493., 399157., 420531., 
   444918., 455485., 452475., 443853., 438708., 436616., 433360., 
   443394., 445043., 452670., 447656., 431500., 433817., 431185., 
   431045., 421231., 421791., 419369., 415861., 415005., 406147., 
   413990., 403282., 418967., 412927., 409442., 400765., 381494., 
   287013., 281008., 272477., 251224., 226014., 236255., 247953., 
   243974., 239400., 238560., 233509., 233675., 220211., 221785., 
   207813., 199911., 177746., 162828., 147133., 132731., 118113., 
   99694., 84923., 71615., 57824., 45756., 20755., 13293., 9197., 
   6124., 4666., 5124., 3040., 1790., 1239., 1464.};
lab = {0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 
   14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 
   27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38., 39., 
   40., 41., 42., 43., 44., 45., 46., 47., 48., 49., 50., 51., 52., 
   53., 54., 55., 56., 57., 58., 59., 60., 61., 62., 63., 64., 65., 
   66., 67., 68., 69., 70., 71., 72., 73., 74., 75., 76., 77., 78., 
   79., 80., 81., 82., 83., 84., 85., 86., 87., 88., 89., 90., 91., 
   92., 93., 94., 95., 96., 97., 98., 99., 100., 101., 102., 103., 
   104., 105};
```

Comment: In all cases both solutions are very nice Thanks

Comment: After looking back at the first code I haven't found explicitely the syntax StringTemplate["``-``"][5 (# - 1), 5 (# - 1) + 4] & I need a little more help.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki I think C.E. would be the person to ask. I am going to bed in my Timezone, so sorry if I do not respond:)